# Nuxt plugins Medium-zoom load image weridly

Tags: nuxt.js

i am using nuxt with medium-zoom, when click from nuxt-link to product page, switching the image and zoom in have no problem, but if you directly load from the product page, when switch the image and zoom in, it have werid effect, if anyone one know why please let me know.

```
<template>
    <div class="ps-product__header">
        <div class="ps-product__thumbnail" data-vertical="false">

            <div class="ps-wrapper">
                <div class="ps-product__gallery">
                    <div class="col-12 px-md-2 d-none d-md-block">
                        <div class="" style="cursor: pointer">
                                        <b-img
                                :src="teaserImage.image"
                                style="width:400px; height:400px;" class="image zoom"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </br>

            <div class="ps-product__variants">
                <div class="col-12 d-none d-md-block my-4">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-3" v-for="(item, index) in product" :key="index">
                            <div class="thumbnail" style="cursor: pointer" @click="changeTeaserImage(index)">
                                <b-img :src="`${item.image}`" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left;" alt="" class="image"></b-img>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
</template>
```

here is the function

```
   export default {
        name: 'ShopProductHeader',
        data() {
            return {
                activeIndex: 0
            }
        },
        props: {
            product: {
                type: Array,
                required: true
            }
        },
        computed: {
            teaserImage() {
                return this.product[this.activeIndex]
            }
        },
        methods: {
            changeTeaserImage(i) {
                this.activeIndex = i
            },
        },

    }
```

try on the sample.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-pake3o?file=components%2FShopHeader.vue

**1.click the product link and switch and zoom in by click the large image**

**2.type /product on the stackblitz browers and try switch and zoom again, you will see the image will now change to behide.**

Comment: It's either CSS selector issue or just some bug regarding the library.

Comment: @kissu hello again kissu, i am not sure too, not sure didt i setup something on my framework or is css or bug.